# Heroku - DNSimple configuration

Tags: heroku, dns, ssl-certificate, dnsimple

Trying to set up SSL to work on mydomain.com. Following Heroku documentation I have managed get the SSL working on https://secure.mydomain.com. However actual endpoint created by heroku when i added the SSL is still saying

```
**Heroku | No such app**

There is no app configured at that hostname.
Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.
```

I am a little confused as to how i get the **tokyo-2121.herokussl.com** to point to my actual application on Heroku.

```
emet:myapp vezu$ heroku certs
Endpoint                  Common Name(s)         Expires                   Trusted
------------------------  ---------------------  ------------------------  -------
tokyo-2121.herokussl.com  secure.mydomain.com  2013-09-09 12:28:05 CEST     True
```

Then

```
emet:myapp vezu$ heroku certs:info
Fetching information on SSL endpoint tokyo-2121.herokussl.com... done
Certificate details:
    subject: /serialNumber=htilpsjjgrrlhyVZ8rbeandz78555bgpWx/FDEVd/OU=GT166968518/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=secure.mydomain.com
    start date: 2012-09-06 12:38:54 CEST
    expire date: 2013-09-09 12:28:05 CEST
    common name(s): secure.mydomain.com
    issuer: /serialNumber=htilpsjjgrrlhyVZ8rbeandz78555bgpWx/FDEVd/OU=GT166968518/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=secure.mydomain.com
    SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.
```

I assume that this means i have installed the SSL correctly. My dnsimple config looks like this

```
Type    Name                     TTL          Points to 
ALIAS   mydomain.com             3600         proxy.herokuapp.com   
CNAME   secure.mydomain.com  600          tokyo-2121.herokussl.com  
CNAME   www.mydomain.com     3600         proxy.herokuapp.com   
MX          mydomain.com             600          mx00.1and1.co.uk (P:10)   
MX          mydomain.com             600          mx01.1and1.co.uk (P:20)
```

How to get the endpoint **tokyo-2121.herokussl.com** to link to my app? Should i be adding it anywhere on my app?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you've configured the SSL endpoint correctly but not told Heroku what domain you will be using. This error message is actually coming from within Heroku meaning that when typing the hostname you're being directed to the correct place but Heroku doesn't recognise the hostname and therefore cannot determine which site to serve.

You need to take a look at the `heroku domains` command.

You can list the domains using:

```
heroku domains
```

If the domain does not appear within the list then you will need to add it. You can do this using:

```
heroku domains:add secure.mydomain.com
```

This will add the domain to your Heroku app so that the Heroku servers serve your site for any requests to that host name.

Comment: Dude, you have just made my day. Thanks a lot. I wonder why Heroku doesn't add this to their documentation.

Comment: :-) There's a link at the bottom of the article actually. Might be worth feeding it back to them.

Comment: Could you use appname.herokuapp.com instead of proxy.herokuapp.com, and forego the heroku CLI step?

Comment: not sure what you mean with proxy but you could set it up using the GUI on their site as well

Comment: +1 for this.  These days when I have some odd error I just google the error message and look for the stackoverflow thread.  (It's not like you'd find this resolution as easily on the Heroku site.)